# Route Config - The resource cannot be found error Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

1- i am Createnew Project MVC Empty and i add new Controller name Home :

```
public class Home : Controller

    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

2- and i am moving in Index and craete right to add view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
```

but were i am debugg my project tell me ASP MVC Route Config - The resource cannot be found error
info : and in  RouteConfig i have this method

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
        }
```

Comment: Did you register your route?

Comment: @RajeshG Yes i do.

Comment: controller name should be ``HomeController`` no?